# jQuery - backgroundColor animation not running (color lib included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have included the jQuery Color Animation library (http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) in the header, and likewise have also tried the jQuery UI library; no matter what I do, I cannot get a backgroundColor animation to play.
Included like so:

- src="code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
- src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"

(with script tags but stackoverflow doesn't let me post those here).

My code:

```
  $("#section__info__what").hover(function() {
  $(profileWhatPathlines).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#FFBF28"
  }, 1000 );
}
```

Other animations (like width) run fine, just not the color animation that I want. Have also tried a host of other elements to run the code on, same issue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers,

Dean

EDIT: "profileWhtPathlines" corresponds is a variable consisiting of a few other variables that reference IDs. Same issue if I just put in a random id though (e.g.: "#demo"). Animation runs (like width), but not the color. So it finds whatever it needs to change but doesn't want to run the color part.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is profileWhatPathlines?If it is an id, you should write as $("#profileWhatPathlines").

Comment: what's the value for profileWhatPathlines? Can you post the relative html?

Comment: It's a variable consisiting of a few other variables that reference IDs. Same issue if I just put in a random id though (e.g.: "#demo"). Animation runs (like width), but not the color.

Comment: Well the width animation is provided by jQuery directly. The color animation is provided by the color-animation library.

Comment: Right, so for some reason it's not using the color library but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Post relevant HTML, please.

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"></script>

Comment: I recommend you try including jqueryui and use the color animation provided through this : https://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: Same issue: " and likewise have also tried the jQuery UI library; no matter what I do, I cannot get a backgroundColor animation to play."

Comment: You'll need to post the html if you want help with this. You should edit the question to include it.

Comment: Hi David, the html of what exactly? No element whatsoever works, I've tried multiple elements so I don't think there's any relevant HTML to post here beyond what I already have mentioned?

Comment: Actually, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vkocu0r9/ You should re-check your HTML and your vars, definitely....

Comment: @nevermind: It finds the selector I am feeding it, as I can see a "width" animation play if I add that. So I can't see an issue with the HTML...I know there's an issue in general somewhere obviously but it eludes me and I don't think it's the code for the element...

Comment: @DeanVaessen, is this your complete JS code? Please try to make non-working example here, or on jsfiddle... Probably you will find problem, during the process... :)

Comment: @nevermind: I'm starting to think this might be an issue with the way my Yeoman/Gulp system is set up because even if I change the whole thing to the way your jsFiddle looks, it still doesn't run. I'll investigate a bit further.

Comment: @DeanVaessen could you please my last solution?

Comment: Fixed it. The issue was that it was loading ANOTHER version of jQuery somewhere deeper in my HTML. So in effect it did this: Load jQuery, load coloranimationlib, load jQuery. Works fine after I removed it. Thanks for the help and your time. Everyone else included :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the jquery.animate-colors.js **AFTER** the jquery.js?

Works fine to me, example: https://jsfiddle.net/7ggq3dka/

```
<!--jQuery loaded first -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Then color animation plugin -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"
```

Comment: There are more libraries like jquery-ui included before?

Comment: Only jquery itself and then the color lib

Answer (score 0):

Well..I have checked the description of the jQuery animate function and it states that string values **cannot be animated** (like "background-color:red").

You can find the all properties, which can be used with the animate function, here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

Here is my solution:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="section__info__what">
  <div id="example"></div>
</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#section__info__what').hover(function() {
        $('#example').css({
            'background-color':'#FFBF28',
            'width': '150px'
        });
    }, function() {
        // on mouseout, reset the color
        $('#example').css({
            'background-color':'#000',
            'width': '100px'
        });
    });
});
```

and CSS:

```
#example {
  background-color: #000;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
   transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

I have used the css `transition` property to animate.

Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8b1d1u0p/1/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The issue was that it was loading ANOTHER version of jQuery somewhere deeper in my HTML. So in effect it did this: Load jQuery, load coloranimationlib, load jQuery. Works fine after I removed it/included the animation library a second time. Thanks for the help and your time guys!